# Key press events outside of python window (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, events

How can I detect a key press outside of a python window(something like a tkinter window). So for example if I pressed the 'a' key while on Chrome, how would I detect I pressed that?

Comment: `pynput` accomplishes this afaik ... but i hope your not trying to make yet another keylogger

Comment: Thank you, and no I'm not making a keylogger. It's to activate things with a key press.

Comment: I was just messing around with it and when I play this game while it's running I continue to walk forward when I press 'w' once. Any ideas how to prevent this?

Comment: I've also just noticed that if I put a delay in the function it slows down all my actions on the computer.